# RxJava 1 Completable.concat Not Waiting for the Previous Completable to Complete

Tags: android, rx-java

I am using RxJava 1 (1.3.6) in an Android application to control the application startup flow.

The first thing that the app does on startup is make a single network request for some configuration values, then after that, initializes 2 different parts of the app (both which make networks requests). To do that, all 3 of the aforementioned startup items are wrapped in a methods that return `Completable`s. Essentially, each method looks like this:

```
private Completable initializeConfig(String configUrl) {
    return Completable.fromSingle(configProvider.requestConfigSingle(configUrl)
            .doOnSuccess(configResponse -> {
                // store the application configuration
                storeConfig(configResponse);
            }));
}
```

This is just the configuration method, but the other 2 methods look pretty much like this one: fetch some network information, sore the data, etc. and all return `Completable`s and are asynchronous.

To control the startup flow, I am trying to use the `Completable.concat` method like this:

```
@Override
public Completable startup(final String configUrl) {
    return Completable.concat(initializeConfig(configUrl), Completable.merge(initializeFirstPart(), initializeSecondPart()));
}
```

What I am seeing is that the `initializeConfig` method is invoked and before that `Completable` has completed, both the `initializeFirstPart` and `initializeSecondPart` methods are invoked.

What I expected to see is that the `initializeConfig` method would be invoked and when that `Completable` finishes, the `initializeFirstPart` and `initializeSecondPart` methods would be called and ran in parallel.

Am I missing something or not understanding how the `Completable.concat` method works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `startup` method invokes those methods directly because there is no magic (language feature) that automatically defers execution of method invocations within parenthesis. In other words, this is what you wrote:

```
@Override
public Completable startup(final String configUrl) {
    Completable c1 = initializeConfig(configUrl);
    Completable c2 = initializeFirstPart();
    Completable c3 = initializeSecondPart();
    return Completable.concat(c1, Completable.merge(c2, c3));
}
```

You should defer the execution of c2 and c3:

```
@Override
public Completable startup(final String configUrl) {
    Completable c1 = initializeConfig(configUrl);
    Completable c2 = Completable.defer(() -> initializeFirstPart())
                         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
    Completable c3 = Completable.defer(() -> initializeSecondPart())
                         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation());
    return Completable.concat(c1, Completable.merge(c2, c3));
}
```

Comment: This did in fact fix the issue that I was having. Thanks! I do understand that the methods are invoked (and are not deferred), but since those methods were just creating the Completables and not subscribing to them directly in those 3 initialize methods, I thought that the flow would be controlled when something subscribed to the Completable that was returned from the startup method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `andThen` instead of `concat`,which will execute second `completable` after first one

```
 @Override
    public Completable startup(final String configUrl) {
      Completable init = initializeConfig(configUrl);
      init.andThen(Completable.merge(initializeFirstPart(), 
      initializeSecondPart()).await());
    }
```